# How to send array type parameter with AngularJS $http.delete?

Tags: angularjs

How to send array type parameter with AngularJS $http.delete

```
// notificationIds is array of ids.
deleteNotification(notificationIds) {
   let query = `/notifications`
   let params = {}
   notificationIds.forEach((id, index) => {
     params[`notificationIds[${index}]`] = id
   })
   return $http.delete(`wis`, query, params)
      .then((response) => response)
}
```

==> but the result is : (Bad Request!!)

Request Method:DELETE

Status Code:400 Bad Request

Comment: did you try adding header?

Comment: Yes I added that headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'} but still the same problem, I do not know what value for the header to have the 'Form data'

Comment: can you check what is getting passed in your header

Comment: did you try `$http.delete( 'wis', query, {params:params})
      .then((response) => response)`

Comment: Why not use a request body   
    $http({
      method: 'delete',
      url: '/notifications'
      data: notificationIds
    }).then((response) => response)

Comment: The same problem 400(Bad request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to thank you all :). This Is the Right Answer

```
deleteNotification(notificationIds) {
    let query = `/notifications`
    let data = ''
    notificationIds.forEach((id, index) => {
      data.length > 0 ? data += '&' : data += ''
      data += `notificationIds[${index}]=${id}`
    })
    const config = {
      data: data,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' }
    }
    return this.ApiService
      .delete(`wis`, query, config)
      .then((response) => response)
  }
```